# Is it possible to quantify the effects of a chelating agent?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, coordination-compounds

If one wants to see what compound is a more effective chelating agent, how does that get measured?

Comment: You could take an NMR of an equimolar Lewis acid/base mixture and see how much free base there is relative to the how much chelate there is. Are you specifically referring to polydentate coordinating agents or any coordinating Lewis bases?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for unanswered questions about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a good starting point is the Formation Constant (β) between the metal and the ligand. The greater the constant, the better the ligand is be at chelating the metal center (as evidenced by the free energy change).

[image: Formation constants and the chelating effect]

Comment: Yes, you can always look this up, but how are they measured in the first place. That might provide a better answer to the question.